# SwiftUI Button with clippedShape "Capsule" glitching on macOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

## Problem

I am trying to create two pill-like, circular buttons using the following code. On iPadOS & iOS, everything works fine. However, if I put the preview device to my MacBook, things start glitching as depicted on the picture.

[image: glitch on macOS]

This is the according code:

```swift
struct ButtonBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Spacer()
            Button {
                // action not yet implemented
            } label: {
                Text("Cancel")
                    .font(FontFamily.CustomFont.regular.swiftUIFont(fixedSize: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 39, bottom: 12, trailing: 39))
                    .background(Color(Theme.CustomGrayColor))
                    .clipShape(Capsule(style: .circular))
            }
            Button {
                // action not yet implemented
            } label: {
                Text("Share")
                    .font(FontFamily.CustomFont.regular.swiftUIFont(fixedSize: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(Theme.CustomGrayColor))
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 39, bottom: 12, trailing: 39))
                    .background(Color(Theme.CustomOrangeColor))
                    .clipShape(Capsule(style: .circular))
            }

        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 0, bottom: 24, trailing: 24))
        .background(
            Color(Theme.CustomGrayColor2)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.25), radius: 12, x: 0, y: 0)
        )
    }
}

struct ButtonBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ButtonBar()
    }
}
```

Now, this is where the weird part comes in: on iOS, everything works perfectly fine using above code, and the buttons look like this:

[image: buttons working perfectly fine on iOS]

## Question

I was expecting that SwiftUI displays things correctly on both platforms automatically (isn't that the biggest benefit of SwiftUI vs. UIKit/AppKit?).

**How can I solve this issue and make the buttons on macOS look just like the buttons on iOS, without creating a separate view for the different platforms?**

Answer (score 2):

## Approach

- Use `.buttonStyle(.plain)`

## Best to follow Apple's HIG (design guidelines)

- The button you are attempting is not common on macOS.
- IMHO I feel (I could be wrong) it doesn't adhere to the design guidelines for the macOS.
- **Suggestion:** Reduce the corner radius for the macOS

## Simplified version of your button

- I still to prefer to use the default button for the Mac.
- This would look odd on the Mac, but since you asked it is below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("pressed")
        } label: {
            Text("some button")
                .padding(12)
                .background(in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .backgroundStyle(.brown)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response! unfortunately, the design is out of my hands and our design department wants the buttons to be round, so they shall be. What is the reason that the views glitch on macOS like that but behave perfectly fine on iOS?

Comment: Apple expects you to use their standard components that are coherent and consistent with the rest of the target system that you develop for. As you can see, bringing your own design is *mostly* possible, but is challenging (if not *very* challenging, especially with SwiftUI) — a point that, unfortunately, a lot of design teams miss and have to be educated on.

Comment: @Vym I couldn't agree more with that. Do you have any (technical) explanation why it doesn't work on macOS though? To me, I thought SwiftUI is supposed to work heartlessly on both iOS and macOS platforms, or am I missing something?

Comment: It *does* work seamlessly (after all, it compiles, runs, and looks very similar, right?)  *while* respecting that platform's design guidelines, which you can read at Apple's website. By iOS conventions, a *default* button appears as just a plain text label. A *default* macOS button has a shape surrounding the label (after all, it's a desktop OS built around a mouse & keyboard interface). Hence the need to explicitly specify the `plain` style if you wish it to become "just a text label" too.